# How to use pan and pinch to zoom gestures in SpriteKit (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I just got started with SpriteKit. This is my GameScene.swift file. My goal is to be able to pinch to zoom and pan the scene, but I have no idea how to get started.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    /* Setup your scene here */
    var circle1 = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50.0)
    circle1.position = CGPointMake(400, 600)
    circle1.name = "1"
    circle1.fillColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
    circle1.strokeColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
    self.addChild(circle1)

    var circle2 = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50.0)
    circle2.position = CGPointMake(600, 400)
    circle2.name = "2"
    circle2.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()
    circle2.strokeColor = SKColor.redColor()
    self.addChild(circle2)
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}
```

I am using Xcode 6.3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=swift+uigesturerecognize

Answer (score -3):

You need to use `PanGestureRecognizers` and `ZoomGestureRecognizers`.

Comment: how exactly are those implemented in context for controlling sprite camera zoom and location?